# Webpack, Html-Webpack-Plugin: Is it possible to specify where to insert the bundle.js file in the template file

Tags: javascript, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

How to specify where to insert the bundle.js inside the template file. I need more control over where exactly my bundle.js file to be inserted.

Html-webpack-plugin allows to specify either - inject: 'head'|'body'